# Does amazon Product Advertising api work for wholefoods and Amazon Fresh?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I know that the api supports Prime, but couldn't make it work with WholeFoods items.

Amazon URLs have a store id (query param: almBrandId), when we browse wholefoods items e.g.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0787Y5CZ4/ref=pd_alm_wf_mzg_1_2_wf_dsk_cp_ai_tcl_1?fpw=alm&almBrandId=VUZHIFdob2xlIEZvb2Rz&pd_rd_r=952ad9da-c060-42d7-960c-20b3ca31b432&pd_rd_w=x0iW6&pd_rd_wg=BdNLi&pd_rd_i=B0787Y5CZ4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0787Y5CZ4)

I tried to add banana to cart using its ASIN, but it is coming back as unavailable, while banana is available on the above link:- (i have removed my associateTag and AWSAccessKeyId, but you can try the link)
https://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html?ASIN.1=B0787Y5CZ4&Quantity.1=3&AssociateTag=a20&AWSAccessKeyId=xyz

Is there any official word regarding Wholefoods being supported through this api?

As a last resort, I used the ASIN, `B0787Y5CZ4` to get its browse-nodes, I only got: "Grocery & Gourmet Food" ("16310101") , "Grocery" ("16310211"), "Fresh Produce" ("6506977011"), "Fresh Fruits" ("16318981").
I was hoping to search 'banana' in any of the above browse nodes or Search Index ('GroceryAndGourmetFood'), and then let my users select the best option. However, that results in a lot of irrelevant recall.

Comment: have the same problem, have you found a solution in the meantime?

Comment: I didn't have any luck. @dsky

Answer (score 0):

It does not. it does have this tho: https://www.amazon.com/afx/ingredients/verify which in the end allows you to at least direct the users to an ingredient pages.